# Cant filter datagrid view vb.net (with example)

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview, filter

I'm not all to familiar with vb.net so I have probably misunderstood somthing here, but hope someone can help

the issue at hand is that i cant filter my datagridview from a textbox. I populate the dataagrid as follows (Which works)

```
        'LOADING XML FILE...
    Dim filepath As String = (IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Projects.xml")
    Dim DS_PROJECTS As New DataSet
    DS_PROJECTS.ReadXml(filepath)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = DS_PROJECTS.Tables(0)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = DS_PROJECTS
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "DATA"
```

then i have a textbox and a button and behind the button i have the following code

```
        Dim filepath As String = (IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Projects.xml")
    Dim DS_PROJECTS As New DataSet
    DS_PROJECTS.ReadXml(filepath)
    DS_PROJECTS.Tables(0).DefaultView.RowFilter = "[STATUS] = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
```

However when I run this code I get the following error:

Additional information: cant find the column [STATUS].

the xml file is as follows;

```
  <COMPELATION>
    <DATA>
      <PROJECT>1</PROJECT>
      <DESCRIPTION>Somthing or other</DESCRIPTION>
      <STATUS>OPEN</STATUS>
      <OWNER>Employee</OWNER>
      <DATE>31-8-2015</DATE>
      <CLIENT>Happy shopper</CLIENT>
    </DATA>
  </COMPELATION>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
 DS_PROJECTS.Tables(0).Select("STATUS = " & TextBox1.Text)
```

If you are binding this data I would recommend putting this into a view and then filter the view and use it.